# Using Angular 2 to bind to pattern attribute

Tags: angular

I'm have a country class that has a property defining a regular expression (string format) for a valid postal code for the associated country.

I have an html select of the countries and am trying to bind the regular expression of the selected country to the pattern attribute of an input box for postal code.

For some reason, the validation always shows as invalid (based on the presence of the ng-invalid class).  The regular expression definitely is not being validated as I've run the same regex in external validators and the validation has passed just fine.

Here is some of the code.  (A [plunk of this is available here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RLwgoIkNiaye1NB4tnKX?p=preview))

```
export var COUNTRIES : Array<ICountry> = [
 {id: 1, name: "United States", zipRegEx: "^\\d{5}(-?\\d{4})?$", requireState: true},
 {id: 2, name: "Canada", zipRegEx: "^[ABCEFGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9][ABCEFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\\s?[0-9][ABCEFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9]$", requireState: true},
 {id: 3, name: "Brazil", zipRegEx: "", requireState: false},
 {id: 4, name: "Australia", zipRegEx: "^(\\d{4})$", requireState: false},
 {id: 5, name: "Faroe Islands", zipRegEx: "^\\d{2}$", requireState: false},
 {id: 6, name: "Papua New Guinea", zipRegEx: "", requireState: false}
];

<label>Country</label>
<select [ngModel]="address.country.id" (change)="countryChange($event)" required>
  <option value="">-- Select a Country --</option>
  <option *ngFor="#country of countries | async | orderBy:{property:'name'}" [value]="country.id" >{{country.name}}</option>
</select><br>

<label>Postal Code</label>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="address.postalcode" [pattern]="address.country?.zipRegEx" /><br>
```

If I use the developer tools, I can see that the binding is working and that the value of pattern is actually being set; however, the ng-invalid class is not properly being applied.

Any thoughts on how this can work using the pattern attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not supported. The `pattern` needs to be added statically in the DOM.

The related Angular2 issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7595

Comment: The pattern validator reads the attribute by `constructor(@Attribute('pattern') pattern)` and I'm pretty sure this doesn't work with attributes added this way.

Comment: Do you know if there are plans to add this ability to Angular 2?  The link you provided seems to indicate that a lot of people think its a good idea but I don't see anything official in regards to an affirmative that validators will be enhanced to work with property bindings.

Comment: It is only a small, probably non-breaking change. I'm quite sure they will change that. The linked issue was created for that. They just have some bigger groundwork tasks they want to complete before working on features and smaller bugs again.

Answer (score 3):

It is supported now by binding to the pattern attribute.

Code below is from: https://plnkr.co/edit/UD9DEoBJ7APs1u4bmGEF?p=info
by Github user: [alexlukin-softgrad](https://github.com/alexlukin-softgrad)

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form #codeInput="ngForm">
      <input type="text" [pattern]="pattern" name="code" [(ngModel)]="codeObj.code" />
      <div>valid: {{codeInput.valid}}</div>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  codeObj = {
    code: ""
  };
  pattern = "^\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*@\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*(\\.\\w{2,3})+$";
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```